# QString from Punycode QUrl

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, punycode, qurl

If I put url `http://www.äsdf.de/bla/bla` into `QUrl`, how can I then restore url with original symbols?

It's ok that `QUrl` will fix some characters, but I'd like to display original `äsdf` in url instead of `xn--sdf-pla`.

I am aware about `QString QUrl::fromAce(const QByteArray &domain)`, but it requires `QByteArray` instead of `QUrl` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`QUrl::toDisplayString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#toDisplayString) with the default `PrettyDecoded` formatting option, or any other value among [enum `ComponentFormattingOption`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#ComponentFormattingOption-enum):

```
QUrl url{"http://www.äsdf.de/bla/bla"};

QString original_string =
    url.toDisplayString(); // default is QUrl::PrettyDecoded

QString original_string_with_encoded_spaces =
    url.toDisplayString(QUrl::EncodeSpaces);
```

Comment: Your sample works fine, but when I use another url with Russian characters "http://привет.рф", then pretty printing fails (still shows Punycode). When I use "http://привет.com", then it's ok. Tested on Qt 5.6.2.